# How to generate an index list from a JSON file in Python?

Tags: python, json

There is a big jsonfile I am trying to manipulate using jmespath. In order to do so I need to generate a full path list to use as reference because not all the items will be needed.

Here is a sample json:

```
data = {
    "firstName": "Jane",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "hobbies": ["running", "sky diving", "singing"],
    "age": 35,
    "children": [
        {
            "firstName": "Alice",
            "age": 6,
            "hobbies": ["swimming", "painting"]
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Bob",
            "age": 8,
            "hobbies": ["video games", "soccer"]
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to script to generate:

```
firstName.Jane
lastName.Doe
hobbies.running
hobbies.sky diving
hobbies.singing
age.35
children[0].firstname.Alice
children[0].age.6
children[0].hobbies.swimming
children[0].hobbies.painting
children[1].firstname.Bob
children[1].age.8
children[1].hobbies.video games
children[1].hobbies.soccer
```

The JSON might be up to 3-4 levels in depth. Been trying several options but can't wrap my head around how to achieve this...

Answer (score 1):

This should work for any depth of JSON (not taking in account recursion limit):

```
data = {
    "firstName": "Jane",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "hobbies": ["running", "sky diving", "singing"],
    "age": 35,
    "children": [
        {
            "firstName": "Alice",
            "age": 6,
            "hobbies": ["swimming", "painting"]
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Bob",
            "age": 8,
            "hobbies": ["video games", "soccer"]
        }
    ]
}

def traverese(d, current_key=''):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k, v in d.items():
            yield from traverese(v, current_key + k + '.')
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for i, vv in enumerate(d):
            yield from traverese(vv, current_key + '[' + str(i) + '].')
    else:
        yield current_key + str(d)

for index in traverese(data):
    print(index)
```

Prints:

```
firstName.Jane
lastName.Doe
hobbies.[0].running
hobbies.[1].sky diving
hobbies.[2].singing
age.35
children.[0].firstName.Alice
children.[0].age.6
children.[0].hobbies.[0].swimming
children.[0].hobbies.[1].painting
children.[1].firstName.Bob
children.[1].age.8
children.[1].hobbies.[0].video games
children.[1].hobbies.[1].soccer
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use recursive code.
This is just a reference of code, and you can use this reference to recursively check with json

```
for keys in data:
    #Here we are checking if type is list or dict
    if type(data[keys]) in [list,dict]:
        for x in data[keys]:
            print(x)
```

Comment: This isn't recursive and doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: You can use it till 3-4 depth. The idea here is to check if datatype is list or dictionary and parse the json

Comment: I said that it is a reference for parsing.